# Retrieve order by status using Salesforce REST API

Tags: java, rest, salesforce

I have an Saleforce app that allows me to execute REST API calls, and I need to retrieve orders (/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Order) by status.

I've found some manual that describes similar filtering on another entitiy (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_placeorder.meta/api_placeorder/sforce_placeorder_rest_api_standalone.htm).

However when trying to execute followin request, it seems that all statuses returned:

```
GET /services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Order?order.status='ddd'
```

I also tried some variations of query params. Is this functionality supported?

Answer (score 0):

`/sobjects` service will let you learn dynamically what fields (standard and custom) exist in Order table (or any other really), what types they are, picklist values...

To retrieve actual data you can use `query` resource. (Salesforce uses a dialect of SQL, called SOQL. If you've never used it before it'll look bit weird the moment you want to do any JOINs, would be nice if a SF developer would fill you in)

This might be a good start

```
/services/data/v47.0/query/?q=SELECT Id, Name, OrderNumber FROM Order WHERE Status = 'Draft' LIMIT 10
```

Never seen the API you've linked to, interesting stuff. But I don't see a[nything obvious that would let you filter by status there](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_placeorder.meta/api_placeorder/sforce_placeorder_rest_api_intro.htm) so the more generic "query anything you wish" might work better for you. Play a bit and perhaps https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm will suit your needs more?

Comment: Will try it. And get back with results. Thanks